# Python - pyqt5 - Alignment of text goes wrong in qtextbrowser when working with a specific font

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qtextbrowser

I have a string array which contains strings of a specific font (සිංහල). When I append those strings to a `qtextbroswer`, alignment goes wrong as

**[this output screenshot.]**

[image]

I think the caused character for this issue is 'නු'. Because it has higher height than other characters.

Following is the code segment I have used for this.

```
self.chars = ['වචන', 'වචනා', 'වචනි','වචනී','වචන', 'වචනු', 'වචනූ', 'වචනෙ', 'වචනේ']
self.textBrowser.append(' '.join(x for x in self.chars))
```

How can I get rid of this issue?

**UPDATE:**

I uploaded the project [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V04XLGhybxhFa6ZhCarnpsyMtxW3mezI).

steps to run:

- run test2.py
- click 'select an image'
- select any image
- click 'upload and test'

Now you will see the output.

Comment: That error does not appear in PyQt5 5.10.1 as I show the following images: https://imgur.com/a/5PMZu

Comment: I'm using PyQt5 5.10.1 . Which point size did you use? I use PointSize 20.

Comment: Using `self.textBrowser.setFontPointSize(20)` https://imgur.com/a/4SAAX

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm still getting that alignment problem. Can it be because of property values of the qtextbrowser? I made UI using 'qt designer'. But I keep default property values as it is.

Comment: @eyllanesc please check the update.

Comment: with PyQt 5.10.1 and Python 3.6.5: https://imgur.com/a/papNE

Comment: @IsharaMadhawa. It is not acceptable to post links to rar files. Copy and paste all the relevant code into your question.

Comment: @IsharaMadhawa. Please also state which platform you are on and which specific font(s) you are using.

Comment: @ekhumoro I'm on Windows , I'm using PyQt 5.10.1 and Python 3.6.4. I have mentioned the string array I use and you can see which font I have used.

Comment: @IsharaMadhawa. Yes, but what is the **name** of that font? What is the output of `print(self.textBrowser.font().family())`? Have you tried using other fonts?

Comment: @ekhumoro Font name is 'Iskoola Pota'. I used English and It works fine. output for `print(self.textBrowser.font().family())` is 'MS Shell Dlg 2'

Comment: @IsharaMadhawa. I cannot reproduce the problem. It works fine using a DejuVu Sans Serif font. I suggest you try using some other fonts, as that is the most common cause of problems like this.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you for the support. I'll update if there is any improvements.

Comment: @IsharaMadhawa. 'MS Shell Dlg 2' is the fallback font on windows, so Qt is not actually using 'Iskoola Pota'. I strongly recommend that you try some other fonts that have good unicode support.

Comment: @ekhumoro I fixed the issue. check my answer. The other thing is Qt supports 'Iskoola Pota' font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by myself. Instead of set font inside a method, I inserted following code into UI itself (using qt designer).

```
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setFamily("Iskoola Pota")
font.setPointSize(20)
self.textBrowser.setFont(font)
```

[image]